# Wording for coach-marks pages

Tags: buttons, controls, first-impression, coachmark

Example of coach-marks:

[image]

While the coach-marks mode is active, what's the clearest way to inform the user that there are more pages with more detailed information?

- an arrow
- A button (more, next, etc.)

The intent is to have the first page as a summary and subsequent pages as a more detailed description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is a button that says "more information" that is clickable and takes them to the subsequent pages. Keep it short and simple for users, this is an occasion where you don't want to over think it. You could even shape the button as an arrow with text inside of it that says "more information".

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using coach marks in the context of a walkthrough. Check out [walkthrough patterns](http://www.mobile-patterns.com/walkthroughs) that use **pagination dots to indicate that there are additional pages**. A good example is Facebook Paper for iPhone.

Comment: Some great inspiration here.